# Permission denied for 'sudo' after 'sudo chmod 666 /usr'

Tags: permissions, sudo, chmod

I have made a big mistake and now I cannot do anything in my work station. I tried to start VirtualBox and it complained that /usr had execution access. Then I executed, wrongly, sudo chmod 666 /usr and now I cannot execute 'sudo' anymore.

I have asked our technical department and they say that Ubuntu has no password for root so they cannot see any solution for my error but reinstall again Ubuntu which means I would lose all my work.

I hope any of you can think of a solution for this problem because. What do you think I should do to gain access again in the /usr or become root user?

Comment: Did you run the `chmod` command with `-R`?

Comment: Having no password for root is not the same as having no root access: quite the opposite, in fact. You should be able to drop directly to a root shell from Recovery Mode and run `chmod` from there.

Comment: Hi Edwinks. No there was no -R. I see now, I in another thread, that I am not the only stupid in this world and that it can be fixed by booting in 'rescue' mode and running cd ..    cd usr    chmod 755 *. Only problem is that I am working remote from home. I hope it calls for a trip to the office :( Shame on me.

Comment: Hi Tony. Cannot 'sudo' as the sudo command is under /usr/bin/ and after executing the chmod 666 it is out of my scope. Any sudo returns a 'Permission denied'.

Comment: If you only did `chmod 666 /usr` there's no reason `bin` should have changed. Do what @steeldriver suggested and use Recovery (enter through GRUB).

Comment: Then you can fix `/usr`.

Comment: @danielsp Whoa. :/ Back to the drawing board...

Comment: @Zanna How so? I thought it was an okay solution.

Comment: **DO NOT** `cd usr chmod 755 *` - that will make things **MUCH** worse

Comment: @steeldriver: That's is what I would have done after reading other posts. What should I do in your opinion?

Comment: @TonyLancer if you use -R here you may as well reinstall, please read up!

Comment: Did you try the full path for sudo?  /usr/bin/sudo chmod 755 /usr

Comment: Daniel, you only need to change permission back on the exact same directory you changed. Your problem is that the parent directory of `sudo` has no execute permission

Comment: @ubfan, Yes, I tried that immediately after my mistake. Cannot, I get the 'Permission denied'.

Comment: @Zanna: Should I? I can hear the whole tech dep. laughs from home :(

Comment: @danielsp Do exactly what steeldriver writes in their answer and you will be fine.

Comment: do exactly what @edwinksl says and you will be fine haha

Comment: Thanks to your comments I'll be able to sleep tonight. Tomorrow, when I am in the office, I'll do as steeldriver says in his answer.

Comment: @ubfan1 sorry I misread your comment! But it is not a path issue

Comment: It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just did `sudo chmod 666 /usr` then things are no too bad - since that will have changed the permissions only on the parent `/usr` directory, not any of the files of subdirectories within it.

If however you added the recursive flag `-R` then you are almost certainly better off re-installing the system. Even so, **there should be no reason to lose data**: you can boot from a live USB or DVD and backup your important files from there first.

*If* you only did a non-recursive `sudo chmod 666` of the `/usr` directory, and you have physical access to the machine, then the simplest fix should be

1. Boot into recovery mode via the grub advanced menu and select 'Drop to root shell'
2. Remount the filesystem in read-write mode

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   ```
3. Execute the command

   ```
   chmod 755 /usr
   ```

   **Don't** add any other command line options and **don't** use any shell wildcards.
4. Type `exit` to continue booting normally

---

Note, `chmod` lives in `/bin` rather than `/usr/bin` so shouldn't be affected by the permissions on `/usr`. If (for example) you'd change the permission bits on the `/bin` directory, or on the `/` directory itself, then this method would not be appropriate since you wouldn't be able to execute `chomd` from recovery mode - the best option in that case would probably be to boot a live CD/DVD/USB of any available Linux distribution (it doesn't need to be Ubuntu); identify and mount the broken system's root device (at `/mnt` in the live system, for example); and then run `chmod 755 /mnt/usr` from the live system.

Answer (score -1):

Your command had possibly removed the SUID-Bit from /usr/bin/sudo 
The correct permissions should be:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 136808 Aug 17 15:20 /usr/bin/sudo
```

You should get a recovery-cd, as mentioned in die comments above and follow the steps in section "finding your root partition". After you successfully mounted it set the SUID-Bit with : chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo

Comment: this is wrong, the permissions of `/usr/bin/sudo` have not been changed - OP's problem is that the `/usr` directory (parent of sudo) has no execute permissions

Comment: thx, i saw your comment regarding the folder-rights which are not set to executeable.  This should be fixed at first.

Comment: The setuid bit on `/usr/bin/sudo` would only be cleared if OP used `-R` flag on `chmod` command, which they did not. If they had done so, their problems would be much worse than not having `sudo`